# ENOENT using fs.appendFile()

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to append data into some files.

Docs says `fs.appendFile`:

> Asynchronously append data to a file, creating the file if it not yet exists, data can be a string or a buffer

```
function appendData(products) {
var productsPromises = products.map(function(product) {
    var title = product['title'];
    return fs.appendFile('/XXXXX/' + title, product, 'utf8', function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
return Promise.all(productsPromises);
}
```

I am getting Error:

> ENOENT, open '/XXXXX/PPPPPPPP'

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `/XXXXX/` is the folder exist in your root of your OS?

Comment: Omg, i was missing a "." i should have placed ./XXXXX/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have accidently added `/` in front of `XXXXX`.

I you expect it to write to a folder `XXXXX` which is located in the same place of where you launched the application, then change your code to:

```
return fs.appendFile('XXXXX/' + title, product, 'utf8', function(err){
```

As `/` In front means root of your filesystem, and the error is common of path does not exist. I.e. there is no `XXXXX` in root of your filesystem, as @Rahil Wazir said.

Comment: Thank you! The simplest / smallest mistakes can sometimes be the hardest to spot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that i forgot to add the dot.

Should be:

```
return fs.appendFile('./XXXXX/' + title, product, 'utf8', function(err){
```

Comment: Yes, `./A` will lead same result as `A`. A matter of preference